# How to catch server's error in inertiajs request?

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

In laravel 8 / inertiajs 0.10 / vue 3  I want to catch some error which happens on server, like :

```
this.form.post(this.route('ads.store'), {
    preserveScroll: true,
    onSuccess: (p) => { // On succdess I see this message
        console.log('onSuccess p::')
        console.log(p)

        Swal.fire(
            'New Ad',
            'Your post has successfully been published!',
            'success'
        )
        this.form.description = null
    },
    onError: (p) => {  // That is not triggered!
        console.log('onError p::')
        console.log(p)
    }
})
```

In control :

```
public function store( AdFormRequest $request) {

    $data = $request->all();
    $data['status']= 'A';

    $ad = Ad::create($data);
    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? new JsonResponse($ad, 200)
        : back()->with('status', 'Error saving add');
}
```

So if one of required fields is empty I got laravel error popup window...
How to catch it and to show it in Swal.fire ?

**MODIFIED # 1:**

Searching in net I found onError property, but making :

```
    this.deleteForm.delete(this.route('ads.destroy', this.nextAd), {
        preserveScroll: true,
        onError: (p) => { // THIS PART IS NOT CALLED ON ERROR
            console.log('onError p::')
            console.log(p)

            Swal.fire(
                'Delete Ad',
                'Error deleting ad!',
                'error'
            )
        },
        onSuccess:()=>{
            Swal.fire( // THIS PART IS CALLED ON SUCCESS
                'Delete Ad',
                'Your post has successfully been Delete!',
                'success'
            )
        }
    })
```

and in control :

```
public function destroy(Request $request, Ad $ad) {
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $ad->deleTTTte();

        DB::commit();
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        DB::rollBack(); // I SEE THIS MESSAGE IN LOG FILE ON ERROR
        \Log::info( '-1 AdController store $e->getMessage() ::' . print_r( $e->getMessage(), true  ) );
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new JsonResponse($ad, 500 /*HTTP_RESPONSE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR*/ )
            : back()->with('status', 'Error adding ad : ' . $e->getMessage());
        return;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? new JsonResponse($ad, HTTP_RESPONSE_OK)
        : back()->with('status', 'Ad saved succesully');
}
```

Which way is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED # 1

Comment: What does your browser's network inspector tell you about the response? Does it contain the expected values and HTTP response code?

Comment: What I see in browser's console : https://prnt.sc/21cbxl9 on error

Answer (score 1):

The onError() callback is only called when there is a specific flag in the session called `errors`. So, in you server's catch block you need to flash the errors in the user's session and redirect to your calling page:

```php
try {
  // errors throw here
} catch {
   return back()->with('errors', 'Error adding ad');
}
```